# Dispatchtimer between buttonpresses

Tags: c#, windows-10-iot-core, dispatchertimer

I'm working on school project with the windows iot C# development sdk, everything is working great so far but now i have two events that need to be triggered after 3seconds and 7seconds. But i can't get it to work, i've been breaking my head over this the last two days but everything i try just seems to give me even more of a headache. So I hope you guys can help me with this.

Basically my program waits for button presses and after a button is released i need to start the timer, but when the button is pressed down the timer needs to be stopped untill button is released again. Down here you guys can find my btn_changed event. Don't mistake the stopwatch built in this event for the timer i need, the stopwatch features a different purpose.

Greetings, 
 Jeroen

```
       private void BtnPin_ValueChanged(GpioPin sender, GpioPinValueChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Edge == GpioPinEdge.FallingEdge) //Execute code when button is pushed down
        {
            stopwatch.Restart(); 
            Debug.WriteLine("Button down");
        } else // Execute code when button is released
        {
            stopwatch.Stop();
            if (stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds <= 5000)
            {
                morsemessage.AddMorse(stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds); //Add the new letter
            }
            else if (stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds > 5000)
            {
                morsemessage.AddCharacter();
                lcd_writestring(morsemessage.GetDecryptedMessage());
            }
            Debug.WriteLine(morsemessage.currentCharacter);
            Debug.WriteLine(stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds);
            Debug.WriteLine(morsemessage.Message);
            Debug.WriteLine(morsemessage.GetDecryptedMessage());
            dispatcherTimer.Start();
        }
```

Comment: Can you detect the edge changed event when you pressed the button and released the button?

Answer (score 0):

I am not clear about what the specific problems you encountered but the following piece of code works for me. You can have a try.

```
    CoreDispatcher dispatcher = Windows.UI.Core.CoreWindow.GetForCurrentThread().Dispatcher;
    private void InitTimer()
    {
        dispatchTimer = new DispatcherTimer();
        dispatchTimer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1);
        dispatchTimer.Tick += (object sender, object e) =>
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Timer tick.");
        };
        dispatchTimer.Start();
    }

    private void InitGpio()
    {
        button = GpioController.GetDefault().OpenPin(4);
        button.DebounceTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 200);
        button.ValueChanged += BtnPin_ValueChanged;
    }

    private async void BtnPin_ValueChanged(GpioPin sender, GpioPinValueChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Edge == GpioPinEdge.FallingEdge)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Button pressed");
            await dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
             {
                 dispatchTimer.Stop();
             }
            );
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Button released");
            await dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
            {
                dispatchTimer.Start();
            }
            );
        }
    }
```